# Limit and intersection of sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be compact Hausdorff. Let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be continuous. Suppose there is a $x\in X$ such that $\bigcap_{n\geq 0} f^n(X)=\{x\}$. How to show the following: $\forall y\in X: \; f^n(y) \rightarrow x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $y\in X$ be arbitrary. For each $n\ge 0$, $f^n(y)\in f^{n}[X]$. If $\langle f^n(y):n\ge 0\rangle\not\to x$, there must be a subsequence $\langle f^{n_k}(y):k\ge 0\rangle$ and an open nbhd $U$ of $x$ such that $f^{n_k}(y)\notin U$ for each $k\ge 0$. For $k\ge 0$ let $F_k=f^{n_k}[X]\setminus U$; the sets $F_k$ are compact, and $F_k\supseteq F_{k+1}$ for $k\ge 0$. Now consider the set $\bigcap_{k\ge 0}F_k$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: I can see that $\cap_{k\geq 0} F_k$ is non empty and compact, but I'm not able to conclude...?

Comment: @Tom: Let $K=\bigcap_{k\ge 0}F_k$; what is $K\cap U$?

Comment: It is empty...I still don't see it :-(

Comment: @Tom: You’re *so* close. On the one hand $K$ is a non-empty subset of $X\setminus U$. On the other hand, $K\subseteq\bigcap_n f^n[X]=\{x\}$. What’s the impossibility here?

Comment: Okay, I think the problem is that I have trouble to convince myself that $\cap f^{n_k}(X) \subset \cap f^n(X)$, since there are more sets intersecting on the right hand side. And I guess this has to be true if we want to have $K\subset \{x\}$...

Comment: @Tom: That’s a reasonable concern; you’re right to worry about it, but in this case there’s no problem, because $f^{n+1}[X]\subseteq f^n[X]$ for each $n$: the sets $f^n[X]$ are a decreasing nest of closed sets.

Comment: That's right, I get it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tom: You’re welcome!